# Determining Hash used to encrypt strings

Tags: string, encryption, hash

I am trying to determine the hash used to encrypt the following strings. From the length of the strings I gather it is a 32 bit hash however Adler32 and CRC32 do not give me the same values.

The original string and hashed value are as follows:

0145 : 68333235

0231 : F538CBE5

0343 : E16BE4A9

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, because ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. This question doesn't have any value for future readers and we're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Comment: If the strings are merely *hashed* (and not *encrypted*) then find a list of 32-bit hash functions, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions, and try each one.

Answer (score 1):

NO, it's not a encrypted string that you will decrypt and find out. Rather it's a hashed string value of the original string and the best way to match is to generate hash value again using the same (or available's)  hashing technique and compare the generated hash value to confirm it.